# Rails -- require foreign key in controller params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a singleton resource that requires a foreign key on #show.  So, I would need to access it with a URL like `http://example.com/product/dash?uid=abcd` where the uid `abcd` belongs to an external resource.

Here's what I have for the class:

```
class SingletonController < ApplicationController
  # this method requires a valid uid param
  def show
    params.require(:uid)
    @user = User.find_by :id => params[:uid]
  end
end
```

I've tried to find an example that uses params.require from Action Controller, but the only examples I've found validate the param values on update, something like `@user.update_attributes!(user_attributes)` where user_attributes is a method that calls params.require and validates that the user object actually exists.  I can't figure out a good way to do that in a `show` method.

What's the best way in Rails 4.0 to check that the foreign object exists and throw an exception if not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Do you just need something that will throw an exception?  ```User.find(params[:uid])``` will throw an exception if the object doesn't exist.

Comment: The foreign key I'm using is not the primary key of the foreign object, so I'm actually doing `User.find_by :key => params[:key]` and that is not throwing an exception.  My example above is overly simplified.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out the best way to do this and follow the Rails model.  A lot of times I will write some semi-custom code only to find out that there's already a method in Rails to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base

> It’s possible to add an exclamation point (!) on the end of the dynamic finders to get them to raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error if they do not return any records, like Person.find_by_last_name!.

So try

```
User.find_by_key! params[:key]
```

to get it to throw an exception.  See also [the official API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) and [the Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Edit:

Note that in plain Ruby the bang means the method is 'dangerous' compared to its non-bang counterpart.  Usually (but not always) that means the method changes its receiver.  Frameworks like Rails may have their own conventions (like in this answer).  When in doubt check the docs.  :)

Comment: Ah!  I didn't know what the bang did.  Cool!

Comment: That's a Rails convention.  In Ruby it indicates that the method will change the method it's called on.  It's important to be aware whether something is a plain Ruby vs. a Rails method.